# VS2019 16.10.3 Intellisense and Compiler warn about bitwise operations. Suggestions?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

The code snippet below is generating an Intellisense Warning:

Using bitwise '~' when logical '!' is probably intended.

But actually bitwise is what I want.   I'm wondering is there something I should do to VS2019 to tell it this is what I want?

```
    unsigned __int8 miniMask  =  ads & 0xFF;             // Lower 8 DUT MASK
    unsigned __int8 miniMask2 = (ads & 0xFF00) >> 8;     // Upper 8 Dut Mask
    unsigned __int8 set       =  miniMask;               // Tester Channel connection
    unsigned __int8 cleared   = ~set;                    // HV connection
    unsigned __int8 set1      =  miniMask2;
    unsigned __int8 cleared1  = ~set1;
```

I just thought I'd post this issue in case someone else sees the same thing someday and wonders "Hey whys it doing that?"

Comment: Does that happen by default or did you enable extra lint warnings?

Comment: Try `unsigned __int8 cleared = set ^ 0xFFu;`.  `~set` is more like `set ^ 0xFFFFFFFFu;` and loses bits when saved.

Comment: So you are suggesting that even though set is declared __int8, the ~set operation is doing internally set ^ 0xFFFFFFFFu; and it's the loss of precision that the compiler is complaining about?
This is interesting, but seems like a compiler/intellesense bug.  I would understand if "set" was a int, but it is declared __int8, so byte wide.  
Thanks, I'll ponder this a bit and maybe submit this case to Microsoft for them to improve Intellisense. (or correct my lack of knowledge)